# Swagger doc has empty paths

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

My Swagger document is not properly generated, I have the basic information (title, name, licence etc) but no doc on my routes.

Here's the setup in Startup.cs :

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<APIContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Version = "v1",
                Title = "OpenWeb Challenge",
                Description = "A 'simple' example ASP.NET Core Web API",
                TermsOfService = new Uri("https://example.com/terms"),
                Contact = new OpenApiContact
                {
                    Name = "Anthony Da Silva Ferreira",
                    Email = string.Empty,
                    Url = new Uri("https://twitter.com/spboyer"),
                }
            });

            var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
            var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
            c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "OpenWebChallenge V1");
        });
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default",pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

And the content of the swagger :

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "OpenWeb Challenge",
    "description": "A 'simple' example ASP.NET Core Web API",
    "termsOfService": "https://example.com/terms",
    "contact": {
      "name": "Anthony Da Silva Ferreira",
      "url": "https://twitter.com/spboyer",
      "email": ""
    },
    "license": {
      "name": "Licence",
      "url": "https://example.com/license"
    },
    "version": "v1"
  },
  "paths": { },
  "components": { }
}
```

Controller sample :

```
public class ContactsController : Controller
{
    private readonly APIContext _context;

    public ContactsController(APIContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Contacts
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.Contacts.ToListAsync());
    }

    // GET: Contacts/Details/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var contact = await _context.Contacts
            .Include(c => c.ContactSkills)
                .ThenInclude(cs => cs.Skill)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

        if (contact == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(contact);
    }
}
```

Am I missing any configuration or something? It's my first time creating API from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the PropertyGroup to the PROJECT_NAME.csproj file?

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
   <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1591</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Without it the compiler will not generate the documentation file.

[Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#xml-comments)

### edit

in the documentation it says: "You must use attribute routing for any controllers that you want represented in your Swagger document(s)" [Link](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#swashbuckle-apiexplorer-and-routing).
so for your controller it would be:

```
[Route("api/contacts")]
public class ContactsController : Controller
{
...

    // GET: Contacts
    [HttpGet("")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
    ...
    }

    // GET: Contacts/Details/5
    [HttpGet("/details/{id?}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details([FromRoute] int? id)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

### edit

i used wrong route template syntax:

```
[HttpGet("/details/:id?")] -> [HttpGet("/details/{id?}")]
```

? for optional parameter

Comment: Yes the property GenerateDocumentationFile is there, I didn't put the NoWarn, is it mandatory ?

Comment: Without NoWarn you will get warnings for missing XML comments, but it is not mandatory. 
Can you share a on of your controllers?

Comment: It gives this error : RoutePatternException: The literal section ':id?' is invalid. Literal sections cannot contain the '?' character.

Comment: Also tried: {id}, there are no errors at runtime but there is one at swagger.json generation.

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake the template syntax in asp.net core is "/details/{id?}". 
the ? is  for optional route parameters.
i use the template syntax for react-router :) sry.

Comment: Sadly same result, I made a post on Stack Exchange Code Review if wanna take a look : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/254742/swagger-doc-and-entity-framework-include-not-working

Answer (score 1):

From your code, the ContactsController seems like a MVC controller (it will return views), instead of API controller.

[The Swagger (OpenAPI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?view=aspnetcore-5.0) is a language-agnostic specification for describing **REST APIs**, instead of MVC Controller. So, it will not generate Swagger document for the MVC controller. Try to add a API controller, then, add API info and description using Swagger.

More details information about using Swagger, check [Get started with Swashbuckle and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)